# Retrieve image from my sql in GWT

Tags: image, gwt

I am working on GWT RPC. I am facing a problem in retrieving image from my SQL.
Here is my code:

```
 Base64 bas = new Base64();

 // sun.misc.BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder(); 
 UploadfileJpaController up = new UploadfileJpaController();

 // this function returns the value in blob field in the form of byte array
 byte[] b = up.findUploadfile(n);

 String base64Contents = enc.encode(b).replaceAll("\\s+", ""); 
 //String base64 = Base64Utils.toBase64(b); 
 base64Contents = "data:image/gif;base64,"+base64Contents;
 return base64Contents;
```

But this is not working.. the image is not displayed. Please help :(

Comment: where is the client side code that tries to display the image?

Answer (score 0):

You should let a regular servlet take care of returning the image data, and not use GWT-RPC. The servlet should set the proper image/gif header and write the binary data to the response outputstream. 
EDIT
This should look somewhat like this

public class FileDownloadServlet extends HttpServletv {

```
// This method is called by the servlet container to process a GET request.
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    // Set content type
    resp.setContentType("image/gif");               

    //Up to you!
    byte[] binaryData = getDataFromDbase();

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(binaryData);
    OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

    // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    while ((count = bis.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
    }
    bis.close();
    out.close();
}
```

}

You url is going to be something like

`http://server/application/image_servlet?id=123545` where you use the id parameter in the servlet to look up the image. And of course add the servlet to you web.xml. Good luck.